# MySQL Query for Advanced Search multiple criteria

Tags: php, mysql, search

I'm working through an advanced search query where users select checkboxes based on multiple criteria.  I'm a beginner so I'm hoping I can find out if I'm on the right track. I'm aware the query is quite the mess.

**Edit: I realized this needed to be two questions, so I've revised to be strictly a query question**

Table data

```
Table ss_users
user_id  first_name   last_name   admin_level   user_approved  
1        nick         jones       0             1      
2        johnny       rocket      0             1      

Table ss_user_profile_status
user_id  photo_uploaded   
1        1
2        1

Table ss_user_photos
photo_id  user_id  filename      selected
1         1        photo_1.jpg   1
2         2        photo_2.jpg   0
3         2        photo_2.jpg   1

Table ss_general
user_id  city        state      zip     neighborhood
1        baltimore   maryland   00125   hamsterdam
2        lakeland    maine      11542   treemont

Table ss_languages
user_id  french  german  italian  spanish
1        0       1       0        1
2        0       0       1        1

Table ss_experience
user_id  waldorf  kumon  homeschooling 
1        0       1       0
2        0       0       1
```

My current results are all users, which should not be the case:

```
SELECT 
    ss_users.*, ss_user_profile_status.*, ss_user_photos.*, ss_general.*, 
    ss_languages.*, ss_experience.*, ss_users.user_id AS userID, 
    ss_user_profile_status.user_id, ss_languages.user_id AS langID
FROM 
    ss_users
JOIN 
    ss_user_profile_status ON ss_users.user_id = ss_user_profile_status.user_id
LEFT JOIN 
    ss_user_photos ON ss_users.user_id = ss_user_photos.user_id
AND 
    ss_user_photos.selected = 1
LEFT JOIN 
    ss_languages ON ss_users.user_id = ss_languages.user_id
LEFT JOIN 
    ss_general ON ss_users.user_id = ss_general.user_id
LEFT JOIN 
    ss_experience ON ss_users.user_id = ss_experience.user_id
WHERE 
    ss_users.user_id = ss_user_profile_status.user_id 
AND 
    ss_general.neighborhood_select LIKE '%hamsterdam%'
OR 
    ss_languages.spanish = 1
OR 
    ss_experience.kumon = 1
AND 
    ss_users.sitter_approved = 1
AND 
    ss_users.admin_level = 0
GROUP BY 
    ss_users.user_id DESC
```

For the output I need to represent much of the users profile, that's why I'm selecting a lot of table data, as well as the extra joins.

Comment: Why do you have $location_data defined twice?

Comment: Without knowing the table structure and what your desired output should be this is going to be hard to answer. Have you considered setting up a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)?

Comment: Thanks @Ray. Just a mistaken when editing here.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Sure, I'll update with some table data. Thanks

Comment: **CAUTION** your source code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. DO NOT concatenate user input witn your SQL Query (_i. e._ `$location = $_POST['location'];

$location_data = "AND ss_general.neighborhood LIKE '%" . implode(" ", $location) . "%'";`

Comment: @PauloASilva The fields (checkbox values) will be escaped. If they are, then is it still problem? It would seem like a lot of work to avoid using the POST data, no?

Comment: @jamie The best way to avoid escaping problems is to use prepared statements and placeholders. What you're doing here is one tiny mistake away from disaster. You say they will be escaped, but you've got one obvious SQL injection bug right here with your `implode` call.

Comment: @tabman: Awesome thanks. I guess that was part of my question. I'm looking at the best way to go about getting the checkbox data. I may not have asked it properly up top

Comment: Is there another way to pull the checkbox array data? There are 30 or so checkboxes for 'languages'. It seemed like the easiest. I've searched quite a bit before posting and implode seemed like the way to go

Comment: Can we get rid of the ss's? They don't seem to be helping. And your languages and experience tables require normalization

Comment: @Strawberry: In what way? Do you mean rather than each item having a column give it an ID? e.g.: user_id  experience_id

Comment: No - although you could do that too. Instead, I mean for instance: `user_id`,`language`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your big fat SQL selection

```
SELECT 
    ss_users.*, ss_user_profile_status.*, ss_user_photos.*, ss_general.*, 
    ss_languages.*, ss_experience.*, ss_users.user_id AS userID, 
    ss_user_profile_status.user_id, ss_languages.user_id AS langID
FROM ss_users
    JOIN ss_user_profile_status ON ss_users.user_id = ss_user_profile_status.user_id
    LEFT JOIN ss_user_photos ON ss_users.user_id = ss_user_photos.user_id AND ss_user_photos.selected = 1
    LEFT JOIN ss_languages ON ss_users.user_id = ss_languages.user_id
    LEFT JOIN ss_general ON ss_users.user_id = ss_general.user_id
    LEFT JOIN ss_experience ON ss_users.user_id = ss_experience.user_id
WHERE 
    ( ss_general.neighborhood_select LIKE '%hamsterdam%' OR ss_languages.spanish = 1 OR ss_experience.kumon = 1 ) AND ss_users.sitter_approved = 1 AND ss_users.admin_level = 0
```

I only edit few places like adding bracket around the OR and remove the first condition cause it seems redundant, and also remove the group by since it will left some data out

Comment: Thanks Li! This gets me my results. Is this the best way to go about it? I'm sure there are some improvements I can make, no?

Comment: I think depends on how often you need the information from other tables, if very often I design a one big fat table instead of several small chunk tables.